# Изменение привилегий файла su

Tags: linux, su

Из-за своей невнимательности и желании установить Linux из Linux Deploy изменил привилегии к файлу su, что находится в /system/xbin. Теперь, как бы я не пытался, назад вернуть не могу. Помогите решить данный вопрос. Телефон Meizu M5c.

Comment: С каких на какие?

Comment: Если бы речь шла о PC, то простейший способ - загрузиться с CD или флэшки и затем поправить права. Но, насколько я понимаю, у Вас телефон... А этот каталог */system/xbin/* он где находится - может быть на флэшке? Тогда, проще всего - достать её и поправить через карт-ридер.